# Link objects from one list to another and drop a new list

Tags: python

Hello friends I have a query, I do not know much about programming but I want to make a short script in Dynamo that allows me to review the elements of a list and link them with another list to generate a new one, for example:

list01 = [500, 900, 1000, 1500, 500, 400]

list02 = [N = 300mm, N = 400mm, N = 500mm, N = 700mm, N = 1000mm, N = 1500mm]

Generating a new list like the following:

list03 = [N = 500mm, N = 900mm, N = 1000mm, N = 1500mm, N = 500mm, N = 400mm]

The purpose of this is to find the elements of the second list that resemble the first and generate a new list in the same order as the first but with the format of the second.

Comment: `[N = 500mm, ...]` is not valid python, please explicit what you really want? (a dictionary maybe? or strings?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a list can have only elements and not key values. You can't write N=100, N=1500 and so on. But yes, you can convert them to strings as "N=100","N=1500". My answer for your question assuming that list02 has string elements, we can traverse the elements of 2nd list from 0 to index 1 using [:2:] and replace it with corresponding index element of list01 using `.replace()` method. Your code:

```
list01 = [500, 900, 1000, 1500, 500, 400]

list02 = ["N=300mm", "N=400mm", "N=500mm", "N=700mm", "N=1000mm", "N=1500mm"]
list03=[]
for i in range(len(list02)):
    l=list02[i][:2:]   #traversing the string to "N="
    n=l+str(list01[i])+"mm"  #converting list01 element to string and adding
    list03.append(n)

print(list03)
```

Answer (score 1):

The constraints are not really clear, but assuming you want a list of strings, you do not really need the second list, just use a list comprehension and formatting:

```
list03 = [f'N = {i}mm' for i in list01]
```

output:

```
['N = 500mm',
 'N = 900mm',
 'N = 1000mm',
 'N = 1500mm',
 'N = 500mm',
 'N = 400mm']
```